# How do I write this elasticsearch query using java APIs

Tags: java, elasticsearch

This following query works correctly and returns the results that I need. I am struggling to write this using JAVA APIs though.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "somepath",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "somepath.key": ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am using this in JAVA. What am I missing? commaSeparatedKeyString = "key1, key2, key3"

```
      QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery(
              "somepath",
              QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("somepath.key", commaSeparatedKeyString)),
              ScoreMode.Total));
```

Comment: Syntax example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-term-level-queries.html#java-query-dsl-terms-query). Each value needs to be a separate string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging purposes, it can be helpful to check the JSON serialization of the query you are building. Fortunately, the toString() methods in the query builders do that for you, so you can simply use System.out.println to print the query builder to stdout (or log it with a logging framework). Assuming that the variable commaSeparatedKeyString is set to "key1,key2,key3" (it sounds like it is, but you don't tell us), you are actually creating the following query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "nested" : {
          "query" : {
            "bool" : {
              "filter" : [
                {
                  "terms" : {
                    "somepath.key" : [
                      "key1,key2,key3"
                    ],
                    "boost" : 1.0
                  }
                }
              ],
              "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          },
          "path" : "somepath",
          "ignore_unmapped" : false,
          "score_mode" : "sum",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are at least two relevant differences in the query you require and the query you are building:

- On the top level, the query you want starts with `"bool.filter..."`, but you are building a query with `"bool.must..."`:

  QueryBuilders.boolQuery().**must**(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery(
- The innermost term query is supposed to have an array of terms (key1, key2, key3). You can't simply pass *one* string with comma separated values to achieve that, but have to pass the terms one by one:

  termsQuery("somepath.key", "key1", "key2", "key3"))